# Como implementar un Sidenav en mi sitio web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Disculpen la molestia.La verdad es que me  mandarían a buscar a Google al leer mi pregunta,pero ya he buscado y buscado y no encuentro un código para implementarlo en mi sitio ya que hacer una cosa así de avanzada esta fuera de mi alcance.

Lo que busco es un sidenav para ponerlo al lado derecho de mi web,el cual ha de ocultarse/mostrarse mediante un botón.

Para ser sincero ya tengo uno.Este sidenav lo he conseguido en la web w3school,pero me da error así:

"Cannot read property 'style' of null".

El sidenav que busco, es del tipo que no arrastra el contenido de la pagina,sino que se sobrepone.Osea de tipo "overlay"

Aquí les dejo el link.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav

¿Alguien podría darme algún link de alguno,pero que no sea usando Angular?

```js
 function openNav() {
   document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
   document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "250px";
   }

function closeNav() {
   document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
   document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight= "0";
  }
```

```css
#wrapper-tabs-o{
 width: 220px;
   }
#wrapper-tabs-o li{
color:  #B0B0B0 ;
  }
  .sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;

  right: 0;
  background-color: #292F33;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;

  }

  .sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: inline;
  transition: 0.3s
  }

   .sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
   color: #f1f1f1;
  }

  .sidenav .closebtn {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 25px;
   font-size: 36px;
   margin-right: 50px;
  }

 #main {
   transition: margin-right .5s;
   padding: 16px;
  }

/*@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
   .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
 }*/
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">x</a>


 <div id="wrapper-tabs-o">
   <ul class="tabs2">

    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1"><i class="fa fa-list" 
     aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
<li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2"><i class="fi-comment"></i></li>

<div class="div_search"></div>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Por cierto este codigo lo tengo en un archivo aparte llamado sidenav.php,el cual esta incrustado en la pagina principal mediante un include("")

Comment: Incluye un [mcve] de otra forma podríamos asumir que es un problema de error tipográfico o no reproducible. Por otro lado, no es apropiado solicitar recursos externos en el sitio principal, para eso está el chat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No necesitas grandes conocimientos para hacer lo que quieres. Te recomiendo encarecidamente aprender los conceptos básicos de HTML, CSS y JS e ir avanzando progresivamente para poder realizar las cosas por tí mismo.

Para hacer un menú lateral tipo overlay solo necesitas tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

- Cómo trasladar el menú. Para esto puedes usar `left` o `transform`.
- Tipo de animación y tiempo de duración
- Extras como sombras, animaciones del ícono burguer, etc.

**Ejemplo**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 let burguer = document.getElementById('burguer');
  let sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');

  burguer.addEventListener('click', function () {
    sidebar.classList.toggle('visible');
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barrio');


*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #f5f7fb;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  height: 100vh;
  left: -231px;
  width: 230px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  position: fixed;
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(.39,.575,.565,1);
  top: 0;
}

.navigation.visible {
  left: 0;
}

.navigation.visible .burguer span:first-child {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.navigation.visible .burguer span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.navigation.visible .burguer span:last-child {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(10px, -10px);
}

.burguer {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 10px;
  outline: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
}

.burguer span {
  background-color: #555;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  transition: all .35s cubic-bezier(.39,.575,.565,1);
  width: 25px;
}

.menus {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.menu a {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #aaa;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Barrio';
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<aside id="sidebar" class="navigation">
  <button id="burguer" class="burguer">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="menus">
    <li class="menu">
      <a href="#">Principal</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu">
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu">
      <a href="#">Portafolio</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

En el código anterior hay algunos aspectos interesantes como la animación del ícono del menú. Esto se logra simplemente rotando las líneas extremas y desvaneciendo la intermedia.

Comment: En realidad tengo nociones de Html y css,lo que falta es aprender javascript,aunque también se un poquito de Jquery.Me falta aprender algunas cosas de css3 y html5,como transform,animation,etc.Gracias por la ayuda. Vere como lo implemento

Comment: De nada. Si mi respuesta te ayudó a resolver tu inconveniente no olvides marcarla como correcta.

Comment: Lo haré.Debo tener tiempo para eso.

Comment: Listo amigo lo he puesto en mi sitio,pero lo he modificado y puesto hacia el lado derecho.Ademas de que cambie el burguer button por uno diferente.Gracias!!